# Comparing elements of ArrayList in loop gives unexpected result?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, java.util.scanner

The following code checks only the first item in the ArrayList. When I type in an item that is in the ArrayList but not in the first position, I get my error message as *"Please enter a valid name"*.

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
   private ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

   for(Account a : accounts)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.printf("Customer name: ");
            String customerName = scanner.next();

            if(customerName.equals(a.getName()))
            {
                System.out.println("You entered " + a.getName());
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: use decent naming: `a` is really meaningless. call it `account`, or `currentAccount` or something.

Comment: I just noticed that you reached upvote rights. That enables you to show your appreciation for helpful beyond accepting answers, as you can now also upvote them ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break from while. When you iterating on list you have to think about logic. Its can be like this code ;

```
ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
boolean isMatched = false;

while (true) {
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        System.out.printf("Customer name: ");
        String customerName = scanner.next();
        if (customerName.equals(account.getName())) {
            isMatched = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isMatched) {
        System.out.println("You entered " + account.getName());
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
}
```

**PS:** `boolean` value to when found the customer name for ending while loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working a little better but the issue now is that if I enter a name that is third in the arrayList, it will repeat the enter message for the other two names, until it reaches the correct name. Why is this?

Comment: I updated the post. Can you check @sg9 ? I changed the printing logic to end of for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop does do that:

```
while(true) {
```

has no purpose here. It simply keeps looping **inside** the outer loop, therefore always comparing against the same `a` account!

Basically you have to swap the two loops!

Comment: I've removed the while loop but same problem is still happening :( for example if I have two names "Tom" and "Sam", the first time i enter Sam it will say invalid name. The second time I enter Sam it will accept it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the infinite while loop.

```
while(true)
```

This loop breaks only when `customerName == firstElement.Name`, else it is an infinite loop. Instead I think what you want to try is moving the while loop outside the for loop. So the code will look something like this.

```
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.printf("Customer name: ");
        String customerName = scanner.next();
        for(Account a : accounts){

           if(customerName.equals(a.getName())){
                 System.out.println("You entered " + a.getName());
                 break;
           }else{
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have it's because you are only checking the first element all the time. Just after you entering your first element, (and breaking your loop while(1)) you will pass to the second one.

Imagine you have in your arrayList

```
"hello", "bye"
```

You'll be inside your loop until texting the first element ("hello").

**Solution:**

```
 while(true)
         {
             System.out.printf("Customer name: ");
             String customerName = scanner.next();
             if (accounts.contains(customerName)){
                 System.out.println("You entered " + customerName);
                 break;
             }
             else{
                 System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
             }
         }
```

Comment: yeah i understand that's what's happening but how can i fix it?

Comment: remove: customerName.equals(a.getName()) and add accounts.contains(customerName)
You have to remove your loop         for(Account a : accounts) as well.